# What are some interesting problems in the intersection of Diophantine Approx and Algebraic Geometry?

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-geometry, soft-question, euler-mascheroni-constant, research

I am a first year graduate student and I am eager to work on irrationality/transcendental proofs of specific numbers like Euler's constant gamma. Because backgrounds for Elliptic Curves include very much of Algebraic Geometry but there is no professor working on Transcendental NT, Analytic NT or Elliptic Curves, so I was wondering is there a subject in the intersection of irrationality/transcendental proofs of specific numbers (or more generally Diophantine approx) with Algebraic Geometry so that I can write a proposal for the professor who works in Algebraic Geometry? I couldn't find any on the Internet.

Comment: The title is helped from https://mathoverflow.net/questions/103243/what-are-some-interesting-problems-in-the-intersection-of-algebraic-number-theor

Comment: I am not really qualified to give full answer, but I think the study of multiple zeta values á la Francis Brown uses lots of tools from algebraic geometry. In this paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/1412.6508.pdf (There is also a nice video lecture on this by Brown) he has written about irrationality proofs. The background seems vast. Some other researchers in this field include e.g. Clément Dupont (If you search his name on YouTube you will find two very nice introductory lectures (French)) and Alexander Goncharov.

Comment: Simulposted to MO, https://mathoverflow.net/questions/396404/what-are-some-interesting-problems-in-the-intersection-of-diophantine-approx-and without notice to either site. Don't do that!

Comment: @GerryMyerson, Why? I didn't know that if it's not legal on StackExchange.

Comment: @k-rational, quite the reverse, your suggestion was very qualified! I emailed your suggested paper and the advisor was happy. Though I will need to find 2018+ paper preferably on Euler's constant not Zetas.

Comment: 1. It leads to duplication of effort. 2. Users on one site may find the idea they need to help you in answers & comments on the other site.

Comment: @L.G. That's great! The notes by Fresán, linked in a comment to an answer below, is a somewhat down-to-earth introduction. Euler's constant does have a relation to the zeta-function, but interestingly, it is an open question of whether or not it is a period; in addition to Fresán's notes there is maybe this paper by Kontsevich, Zagier https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~v1ranick/papers/kontzagi.pdf. I think there is much active research, all related to algebraic geometry (even arithmetic), going on in this field; it all seems highly interesting, I wish you the best of luck :)

Comment: @k-rational, Thank you :)

Answer (score 4):

Such questions may be quite hard in general.

But since you are asking, and you couldn't find anything on the internet, here is something. There is an open conjecture whether or not $\zeta(2n+1)$ is irrational for $n\ge 2$. Here we have results of [Zudilin](https://arxiv.org/abs/1801.09895)
in this direction, which you could start looking at. This has also intersections with algebraic and arithmetic geometry.

You might perhaps also be interested in  Schikhof's conjecture, which is less known. Consider the $p$-adic series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n!$. It converges in $\Bbb Q_p$ since $|n!|_p\to 0$ for $n\to \infty$. The conjecture is, that the limit is a $p$-adic irrational number in $\Bbb Q_p$ for all primes $p$.

Comment: On the note of the conjectures concerning the transcendence of zeta values, let me point to the extremely well written recent book by Burgos Gil and Fresán: http://javier.fresan.perso.math.cnrs.fr/mzv.pdf. Starting essentially from scratch, they introduce the reader to multiple zeta values, and their motivic versions due to Brown, which linearise the transcendence conjectures for single zeta values.